# How can I write an mp3 media link and image using Template Literals

Tags: javascript, template-literals

How can I link these mp3s and availsound.png to the songs and then click song to play using Template Literals? I also can't figure out how to delete the bullets? I can't seem to figure out how to add this in Template Literals. I get the string of text instead of the links and I get a bulleted list when there is no list; it's a span.????

```js
// JavaScript Document

var albumData =[
 { 
  "imageUrl": "music_imgs/covers/genpx1.png",
  "artist": "Gen1artist",
  "name": "Gen1name",
  "release":"released 2017",
  "tracks":[
  {
   "TrackNumber": "1.",
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":" Gen1Track1",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:47"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": "2.",
   "song":" Gen1Track2",
   "duration":"0:00"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": "3.",
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":" Gen1Track3",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"2:52"
  },
  {
   "TrackNumber": "4.",
   "link":"media/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3",
   "song":" Gen1Track4",
   "songimgUrl": "music_imgs/availsound.png",
   "duration":"3:25"
  }
  ]
 }
]

var albtunes = $(`${albumData.map(function(tlist) {
   return tlist.tracks.map(r=>`
     <li class="tracks">
    <span class="songs">${r.TrackNumber + r.song + r.link + r.songimgUrl}</span>
    <span class="time">${r.duration}</span>
   </li>
      `).join('');
      }).join('')
}`);
var playlist=$('#playlist');
$( playlist ).append ( albtunes );
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */
*{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 0.8rem;
 font-weight:bold;
 color:#ffffff;
 background-color:#000000;
}
container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 position: relative;
   padding-top: 5px;
 width:85%;
 height:auto;
 display:block;
}
#music{
 position: relative;
}
#playlist{
 float:right;
 width:60%;
 padding:10px;
   background-color:#373636;
}
.tracks{
 }
.songs{
 float:left;
}
.time{
 float:right;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>playlist_1-15_stackqu</title>
<link href="mus_css/playlist_1-15_stackqu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
 <container>
  <div id="music">
   <div id="playlist">
        <!---<li class="tracks">
    <span class="songs"></span>
    <span class="time"></span>
   </li>--->
   </div>
  </div>
 </container>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="mus_js/playlist_1-15_stackqu.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can't use a `li` outside of an `ul` or `ol`. They be causing them bullets!

Comment: Maybe you meant to use the `a` element with an `href` attribute?

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier Thanks for the input. I bigger issue is linking the media using Template Literals.

Answer (score 1):

In the loop instead of creating a `li` or `span` create a `a` tag with an `href` attribute. The value of the `href` should be the audio file. In your loop, do something like the following.

```
tracks
  .filter(track => track.hasOwnProperty('link')) // Get only the tracks with a link
  .map(track => 
    `<a class="track" href="${track.link}">
      <span class="title">${track.TrackNumber}: ${track.song}</span>
      <span class="duration">${track.duration}</span>
    </a>`)
  .join('');
```

The `filter` method returns a new array tracks that have the `link` property. The `map` will set the `link` property to the `href` attribute in your HTML. 
This will enable the user to click the link and get redirected to the file, which in some browser opens a new tab and automatically starts playing.